# need an regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

Please help I need an regular expressions that can get any other string except specific one, for example I set the specific one to be "abc", then any other string like "bac", "cbaad", etc can be accept, but if "abc", no.

hope that make sense, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

If your specific string is a single string i.e. on abc then you can do it using simple if condition,

```
if(myStr != "abc")
{
    // check myStr with regular expression of required pattern
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As other answers have pointed out there is no need for regex in your simple example, but here is a regex that will do the job just in case you dumbed down your example too much and you actually have a need for something like this.

```
^(?!abc$).*
```

And if `abc` can't occur anywhere in the string:

```
^(?!.*abc).*
```

Comment: @Michael `var match = /^(?!abc$).*/.test("Sample text")`

Answer (score 2):

If "abc" should not occur anywhere in the string,

```
var str = "bcabcd"; 
var noNoStr = "abc";
var pattern = new RegExp(noNoStr);
var result = !pattern.test(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to exclude "abc" only why not do simple comparision... x == 'abc'

i.e

```
if( str == 'abc')
{
...
}else{
...
}
```